# Get to the specific textarea and write data in it from database PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have questions which I'm reading form database and with while loop I show them all, but now I have answers on that questions also in database just in the other table.
So, I need to put those answers into textarea's below every question, for questions without answers just to leave empty textarea.
How can I know in the loop where to put specific answer, I mean how to tide questions-answers?
Thanks.

here is the loop:

```
$j = 1;
    while($rowQuestion = $connector->fetchArray($resultUser)) {

        echo "
            <div class='question'>
                <h4>".$rowQuestion['wq_title']."</h4>
                <p>".$rowQuestion['wq_desc']."</p>
        ";
            $queryAnswer = "SELECT *
            FROM workshop_answers
            WHERE id_user='".$_GET['userid']."' AND q_comp='1' AND id_que='".$j."'";
            $resultAnswer = $connector->query($queryAnswer);
            $rowAnswer = $connector->fetchArray($resultAnswer);

        echo "
            <textarea readonly='readonly' id='".$j."'>".$rowAnswer['q_answer']."</textarea>

            <div class='ftr'>
                <a href='#top' class='pull-right'>Back to Top</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        ";
        $j++;
    }
```

Hey guys I made some modifications and now it works great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left outer join` in your sql query to join the question table and answer table.

Comment: Don't you think that will not show me all questions, only answered I think and I need them all??

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN will retrieve all questions, and if there is matching answer, will retrieve it together else retrieve it as null value.

Comment: I think using LEFT OUTER JOIN is more straightforward as one query is used compare with 2 separate query as i see in your solution above.